# Bulk Inserting a single-column flat file with Unicode characters "truncates" a row

Tags: sql-server

I have the following problem. I have a flat file with several rows of 1400 characters. I run a `BULK INSERT` of this file into a table with a single, `nvarchar(1400)` column.

The statement is the following:

```
BULK INSERT tempTable
FROM 'path\file' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR= '',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',MAXERRORS = 0)
```

This runs properly, with no errors. But on closer examination, I notice there's a row that has been "truncated", at only 230 characters.

After opening the (big) file with Sublime, I found this row is truncated around the appearance of these special characters, like `[NUL]` (the brackets are supposed to be a square, which is the way I see it in Sublime). Something like

```
9999999999999 99999999999991000000JOHN DOE    [NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL]ABCDE99999999
```

Notice, if I open the file with Notepad, the characters are replaced by empty spaces, like so:

```
9999999999999 99999999999991000000JOHN DOE          ABCDE99999999
```

In any case, is there any way to make the bulk insert continue reading the row after finding these characters, instead of truncating it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have face the same problem and we resolved it by using 'SQL Server Import and Export Wizard'. Inside Microsoft SQL server management studio, open object explorer and right click on your database name. Select option Tasks >> Import Data. New SQL Server Import and Export Wizard window will be open. Select Source as flat file and browse your flat file. Under Destination, select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, provide your SQL server name and database name. On next page, Edit mappings (destination table). Hope so, this will work.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the sort of solution I was looking for. This is part of an ETL solution, so the user won't be interacting with the SQL Server directly.